# Geoserver fails One or more listeners failed to start

Tags: tomcat7, osx-yosemite, geoserver

I am running GeoServer 2.7.1 on Tomcat 7.0.62 on OS X 10.10. I have installed Tomcat with Homebrew and copied the GeoServer 2.7.1 war file to the webapps dir. When I try to start GeoServer it fails with this message.

> SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file

I see no other specific errors in catalina.out. Maybe this is an issue below?

> INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable   debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
>   Jun 22, 2015 3:48:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
>   SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
>   Jun 22, 2015 3:48:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
>   SEVERE: Context [/geoserver] startup failed due to previous errors

Anyone know where I can start looking for config errors etc. ?

Comment: There are a lot of possible causes for this, most likely one... not running Java 7 but Java 8 instead. Can you check if you have either OpenJDK or Oracle JRE version 7? (supported java versions: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/production/java.html#use-supported-jre)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @S.L. Barth, that was the problem. I had to downgrade Java8 to Java7. Now it works! This [guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jdk.html) was helpful

Comment: actually for me the opposite worked! I was on Java 7 and upgrading to Java 8 fixed things. Running under a docker container i'm building. Tomcat `7.0.75` + `Java 8` + `Geos 2.10.2`

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, adding setenv.sh file in tomcat/bin folder or changing the jdk path in service script (if you are starting tomcat as a service) resolves this issue. The web-application you are deploying depends on specific jdk version.